# What is the expected behaviour of parent-relative directories in global.json?

Tags: dnx, dnu

(Now raised as [DNX issue 3206](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/3206)...)

DNX environment: 1.0.0-rc1, Windows 10 x64.

Imagine I have three solutions:

- Application1
- Application2
- Common

Each of these solutions has multiple projects in; it wouldn't make sense to have all the projects in a single solution, even though that would simplify this *particular* issue.

Various projects in Application1 and Application2 depend on a project in Common. Their `project.json` files indicate that dependency in a normal way. While eventually I'd like to publish the artifacts from Common to a NuGet server (internal or external), it makes sense to temporarily just build everything from source.

I can do that by editing `global.json` within (say) Application1 to have:

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test", "../Common/src" ], 
  "sdk": { "version": "1.0.0-rc1-final"  }
}
```

With that in place, I can perform a `dnu restore` *from the Application1 directory*... but not from the root directory. (The error is "Unable to locate Dependency 'Common' >= 0.0.0-*".) I can run `dnu restore Application1` from the root directory, but not just `dnu restore`.

I've tried numerous ways to refer to the Common src directory (including "./Common/src", "Common/src", "../repo-name/Common/src"), but haven't had any joy yet. In every case, I get the error message shown above. I've tried using `dnu -v restore` but that didn't appear to give any extra information about which directories were being probed for source-based packages.

So, how *should* the `"../Common/src"` be resolved in `global.json`? Is this a resonable approach to the development scenario I've described, and if so is it just a matter of filing a bug against DNX?

Comment: I'm still learning, but shouldn't you only have one global.json file and it be at the root?

Comment: @KhalidAbuhakmeh: One per solution. This is a case of multiple solutions, each with multiple projects. Will clarify the question.

Comment: No experience in global.json (or dnx); but in general, I try to avoid relative references like "../folder" because are problematic in different contexts. Have you tried to store the Common/src contents inside the folder of the given application and refer to it without the "../" part? Just for testing. To see if this is the problem.

Comment: @varocarbas: I'm sure that would be fine, but not helpful for file organizational purposes. I'm only expecting that the layout in the file system will match the layout in the repo - there's no cross-repo expectations here.

Comment: It was a suggestion for mere testing purposes (to remove potential sources of error; not saying that files cannot locate anywhere, just that perhaps the way you used to refer the path is not supported). For example, PHP's `require`/`include` doesn't allow this format. Anyway... I am sure that you know much more than me about all this. Just trying to help.

Comment: @jon-skeet, your expectation sounds reasonable to me. I would file a bug. :-)

Comment: Hmm well I guess you could get around it by making a symbolic link in the filesystem. Considering you said this was temporary that shouldn't be too big an ask.

Comment: @Michael: It probably would, but there's no way I'm going to stoop that low :) (This really has to work wherever you happen to check out the repo, and on whatever operating system.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I presume that comment was meant to be directed at me ;)
Step it up an extra evil level, pre-build task to create the symbolic link if it doesn't exist. </sarcasm>

Comment: @laurencee: Not sure. It's possible it was aimed at a now-deleted comment...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't work the way you expect it, when you start `dnu restore` it tries to find `global.json` in current or parent directories, and reads project path from it. So in your example it doesn't read anything because `global.json` is in sub-directory.

One way to solve this problem is to add `global.json` to root folder with the following content:

```
{
   "projects": [ "Application/src", "Common/src" ]
}
```

I will ask around about this scenario and if it might change when moving to `dotnet cli`

Comment: So it *only* looks for project.json when searching child directories? That would make sense of the behvaviour, but seem an odd design choice. Will experiment though - thanks!

Comment: Right, having played a bit more, I think this is exactly the problem. Will amend the issue appropriately :)